# Certain files do not show up in Windows Explorer or cmd, but exist

Tags: windows-7

I have a folder of MP3 songs. In Windows Explorer and when doing "dir" in cmd, I see:

```
01 One More Time.mp3
...
14 Too Long.mp3
```

However, there exists a file `folder.jpg` and I can access it by simply typing it into the Explorer address bar, and Winamp and Windows Media Player can all see that file. In Cygwin, when I do `ls`, I get:

```
01 One More Time.mp3
...
14 Too Long.mp3
AlbumArtSmall.jpg
AlbumArt_{E0B5F6EB-9E7A-4290-A301-FD4994D78C20}_Large.jpg
AlbumArt_{E0B5F6EB-9E7A-4290-A301-FD4994D78C20}_Small.jpg
desktop.ini
folder.jpg
```

This is really weird. I can overwrite the file `folder.jpg` with an editor like Vim, but if I download something from Firefox to replace it, Firefox says it cannot modify it since it already exists. Presumably, Firefox uses a Windows API to create the file since a "`dir`" does not list it, but somehow Vim `dir`-ing it finds it.

I am on Windows 7 Ultimate. Show hidden files is turned on.

Edit:

So I just turned on Show System Files, and these appear in Explorer, the icons kind of greyed out. Why on earth are these system files? I manually created the `folder.jpg` file. Firefox still cannot overwrite that file with a download.

Comment: Is "Show system files" turned on?

Comment: No it's not. Now that it is, it shows up. But why are these system files?

Comment: What music software do you have installed and watching this folder? I know that the Zune software can add a bunch of extra files to manage the album art. It could be that a program is setting this file to system.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Windows uses a convention whereby a file named "folder.jpg" located in a given folder is used as the thumnbail image for that folder; so the problem is specific to that particular file name.

Some info on this:
[Here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/920/set-the-thumbnail-that-appears-on-a-windows-folder-or-album-art/)
and [here](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/windowsxp_tips.asp) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ssadasivuni/archive/2003/08/22/24942.aspx)

I guess they're considered system files because if you make a folder full of images, this file is automatically created by Windows and is used in Explorer, My Computer, Windows Media Player, possibly other places, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a command prompt and navigate to your directory with the hidden files. Then type

```
attrib -H -S folder.jpg
```

Replacing folder.jpg with the other file names also

Comment: `attrib -H -S folder.jpg /s` This will (of course) fix this file in all your subfolders too.